# Grouping rows by column 1 value while keeping column 2 values

Tags: microsoft-excel

as an example, i want to transform a table:

```
Tenant  vrf
Ten1    vrf1
Ten1    vrf2
Ten2    vrf4
Ten2    vrf10
```

Into something like:

```
Ten1  ten2
Vrf1  vrf4
Vrf2  vrf10
```

I use this table in powerBi which i want to tranform and make it available as a source query from excel.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

To create your desired output, you can Pivot with no aggregation.

In order to do that without causing an error, you can add an Index column which increments for zero to n depending on the tenant.

- Group by Tenant retaining "All" rows
- Add an index column to each sub group
- Re-expand the table
- Pivot on Tenant with Value=vrf
- Delete the Index column

***M Code***

```
let
    //Source can be your PBI query
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Tenant", type text}, {"vrf", type text}}),
    
//Group Tenant and add Index column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Tenant"}, {
        {"x", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"Index"), type table[vrf=text, Index=Int64.Type]}        
        }),

//expand the table; then Pivot on Tenant and remove the Index column
    #"Expanded x" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "x", {"vrf", "Index"}, {"vrf", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded x", List.Distinct(#"Expanded x"[Tenant]), "Tenant", "vrf"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: the post  answer was modified, can you put back the oldest answer which more intuitive than the last suggested answer, i could make it following the first answer in the oldest post.

Comment: @ZakariaHalil Not sure what you mean. I do not see evidence that I have edited this post.  Had I done so, at the bottom of the answer it would say "*edited on `date/time`*" .  Perhaps you are confusing with another question of yours?

Comment: Hello, sorry for incnvenient, i ve found the correct post with detailed steps:https://superuser.com/questions/1722729/transform-power-bi-table-for-dropdown-list-usage-on-excel/1722771#1722771