# Transform power bi table for dropdown list usage on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

As an example, I want to transform a table:

| Tenant | vrf |
| --- | --- |
| Ten1 | vrf1 |
| Ten1 | vrf2 |
| Ten2 | vrf4 |
| Ten2 | vrf10 |

Into something like:

| Ten1 | Ten2 |
| --- | --- |
| Vrf1 | Vrf4 |
| Vrf2 | Vrf10 |

I use this table in powerBi which I want to transform and make it available as a source query from excel.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can accept the reply of FlexYourData as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Tenant"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Tenant=text, vrf=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"Index",1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Tenant", "vrf", "Index"}, {"Tenant", "vrf", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[Tenant]), "Tenant", "vrf"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Ten1", type text}, {"Ten2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

1. Group by Tenant with Aggregation set to All Rows

[image]

2. Add a custom column which adds an Index to the each group (1,2,3 etc per unique Tenant)

[image]

3. Remove all columns except the custom column added in step 2

[image]

4. Expand the custom column added in step 2

[image]

5. Pivot the Tenant column

[image]

6. Remove the Index column
7. Change the data types

[image]

Comment: That works for me, much appreciated your help.

Comment: you made it so easy for me with this great explanation, i wish you a happy non blocking  life Sir !